# How to take slope of pandas dataframe column with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, plot, sklearn-pandas, graphing

I am trying to find the slope and values of a dataframe column (labeled 'Count') and display as a new list. The problem is that there are multiple company names and have to first be grouped using groupby. Another thing is that each company is by date, which I believe is an object, so I am thinking it has to first be converted to datetime or a value?

Let's call this df:

sample:

```
  |  Date        |Domain|Count|
 +---------------+------+-----+
 0|Feb,1,2019    | c1   |  8  |
 1|March 1, 2019 | c1   |  5  |
 2|April 1,2019  | c1   |  4  |
 3|Feb,1,2019    | c2   |  2  |
 4|March 1, 2019 | c2   |  6  |
 5|April 1,2019  | c2   |  9  |
 6|Feb,1,2019    | c3   |  1  |
 7|March 1, 2019 | c3   |  3  |
 8|April 1,2019  | c3   |  7  |
```

want to display as:

```
    slope | intercept | yval | pval
c1  456       667        5      6
c2  3          4         6      8
```

(made these numbers up)

```
df.groupby('Domain').apply(lambda v: linregress(v.Date, v.Count)[0])
```

sklearn reg.fit might also work here?

Comment: thank you! New user here :)